# Windows software for custom shortcut keys

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like a software which allow me to create custom shortcut key like:

- Shortcut to my Dropbox folder
- Shortcut to open my text editor
- Shortcut to write my usual password (bad idea I know)
- Shortcut to one of my favorite webpages

Requirement:

- Works on Windows
- Very easy to configure (for people nervous with IT)
- Runs at OS's startup
- Very light software

Comment: [Built-in method](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-keyboard-shortcuts-open-programs#1TC=windows-7) tldr: In Shortcut's Properties you can set Shortcut key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried [Clavier+](http://utilfr42.free.fr/util/Clavier.php?sLang=en) which is a very light software (87Ko). It allows a wide variety of functionality, like specific key detection when an other programm is running. And the customization is quite easy. Of course it automatically runs on computer startup.

The soft can be installed, but it's not required. So you can easily take it on an USB key. Your key configuration is embedded into a *.ini* file which allow you to export (and save) it where you want.

It´s free and 6 languages are provided : French, English, German, Brazilian, Portuguese and Russian.

A screenshot of the configuration interface (French translation here) :

[image: Clavier+ example]

Answer (score 11):

Been a while since I used it but [AHK](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (Auto HotKey) works well for all of those IIRC, and is very easy to setup but if you want you can do scripting to do fairly complicated tasks.
To be specific:

- It is designed for Windows
- I recall it as being very easy to configure the basics (you can do a lot more than basics with it if you want but you don't have to)
- Autostart last I used it anyways was automatic (of course any windows program you can manually set to autostart through `reg edit` but if you are nervous about IT topics not having an automatic start could be a downside)
- I never noticed any impact on my system - again been a couple years but I last used it on a Compaq laptop with Win 2000, 1GB Ram, 40GB HD.

Answer (score 9):

For the most part, Windows itself provides what you want natively. You can define keyboard shortcuts for a command line (in the shortcut editor). The command line can be for the `explorer` application to open a folder, or for the web browser to open a web page. This meets your requirements except for entering your password.

Most of the time a password is something you type in a web browser, and all major web browsers include a password manager. (You have to type your login password, otherwise you might as well not have one at all.) Keeping your password in the browser's password manager has advantages: they're all stored in one place, and the risk of accidentally entering them in the wrong place is low. Some web pages [disable password saving](https://superuser.com/questions/604603/password-memorization-and-autocomplete-heuristics-in-chrome) for no good reason; for the same reasons I recommend a browser-based solution such as [Autofill](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autofill/nlmmgnhgdeffjkdckmikfpnddkbbfkkk?hl=en).

If you want to be able to insert arbitrary text in arbitrary applications, the gold standard seems to be [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (open source). It's fairly powerful, it lets you start applications, manipulate windows and inject keystrokes. The macro syntax is horrible, but there are good tutorials on the website. There are a few examples of password insertion scripts on the forum [1](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/88125-need-a-script-to-fill-out-usernamepassword/) [2](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/68418-insert-login-in-a-webpage/) [etc](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=008894931886257774458:qsymwz_o1tq&hl=en&q=password).

Answer (score 3):

I developed [Quick Access Popup](http://www.quickaccesspopup.com) using AHK. This freeware lets you collect favorite folders, apps, documents, web links, etc. in a popup menu that you can invoke in any application.

If you prefer keyboard shortcuts, you can assign favorites to hotkeys. A hotkey manager lets you review the assigned hotkeys and add/edit/remove hotkeys. The popup menu can include submenus. Each submenu can also be assigned to a hotkey.

[See this video for more info](http://www.quickaccesspopup.com/quick-access-popup-features-overview/). Quick Access Popup does more than what you look for but but I think you will like all it offers to make you more efficient working with your PC.